# Индексация группы чисел массива

Tags: c++

Массив:

```
float v[] = {
0.5, 0,5, 0.0,
1.0, 0.5, 0.0,
0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
-0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
1.0, 0.5, 0.0,
0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
0.5, 0.5, 1.0}
```

нужно проиндексировать каждую группу из трёх чисел массива целыми числами начиная с нуля и записать индексы в другой массив, т.е. для первых трёх чисел будет всегда 0.

например: 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс ноль,

1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1,

0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс ноль(т.к. группа уже встречалась),

-0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 2,

1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1,

0.5, 0.5, 1.0 - индекс 3 и т.д.

В итоге новый массив должен получится таким: int v2[] = {0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3}

Comment: а вопрос какой?

Comment: поможет обычная сортировка пузырьком. Только чуточку переделать нужно - не обменивать, а индексы прописывать

Comment: Создайте третий массив, и выполните цикл по каждому элементу 1 массива, если элемента нет в 3-ем массиве, мы во второй массив присваиваем увеличенный счетчик массива, в 3 массив добавляем текущий элемент. Если элемент есть в 3 массиве, во 2 массив добавляем индекс элемента в 3 массиве.

Comment: по этой логике последный индекс не 3 а 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется задача простая, если поразмыслить мозгами

Вот код:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void OutputArray(const T *array) {
    int i = 0;
    while (array[i + 1] != *"exit") {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
//  Инициализация
    float arr0[] = {
        0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 1.0
    };
        int *arr1 = new int[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; arr1[i] = -1, i++) {};
        int cnt = 0;
//  Реализация
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i += 3) {
            if (arr1[int(i / 3)] == -1) {
                for (int j = i; j < 21; j += 3) {
                    if (arr0[i] == arr0[j] && arr0[i+1] == arr0[j+1] &&                                                    
                    arr0[i+2] == arr0[j+2]) {
                    arr1[int(j / 3)] = cnt;
                }
            }
        cnt++;
        }
    }
    arr1[8] = *"exit";
    OutputArray<int>((arr1)); // Чисто для красоты
//  Финализация
    delete arr1;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Алгоритм основан на том что если в массиве arr1 элемент обозначен как -1 то он не имеет индекса и мы во 2 цикле даем ему индекс. j не от 0. так как все элементы сзади уже проиндексированны. 1 элемент в массиве arr1 это общий индекс 3 элементов массива arr0. Надеюсь понятно.

Comment: как всё просто.

Comment: UB в `delete arr1;` и для больших массивов будет неправильно печатать из-за `array[i + 1] != *"exit"`